# How to replicate holes in a wooden cabinet?

Tags: drill, wooden-furniture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I drill additional holes for adjustable-height shelving?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2535/how-do-i-drill-additional-holes-for-adjustable-height-shelving)

I would like to modify the vertical position of a shelf inside a wood cabinet. The dowel pins are glued on the shelf only. How can I replicate the holes on the cabinet? I already have the transfer plugs, and I feel they could be useful in this situation.